# What motor and remote control can be used for LEGO train 60197?

Tags: motor

I got the LEGO set 60197 passenger train and its missing the 3 components. The motor, the battery, and the remote. I've tried to look online for it but the only motor I see online is 88011. Is that compatible?

Comment: If you happen to have the appropriate kind of conductive track, 60197 can also be powered with the older 9v or 12v motors (part nos. 590 / bb0012v).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have been nice to know you location, to provide direct URLs. Below are details for UK, however prices would be in similar price range in other markets.

- Train motor [LEGO](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/product/train-motor-88011) | [Bricklink (as part)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?P=bb0896c01&colorID=11) | [Bricklink (as set)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=88011-1#T=P)
- Remote Control [LEGO](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/product/remote-control-88010) | [Bricklink (as part)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?P=28739c01&colorID=1) | [Bricklink (as set)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=88010-1#T=P)
- Hub [LEGO](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/product/hub-88009) | [Bricklink (as part)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?P=bb0892c01&colorID=1) | [Bricklink (as set)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=88009-1#T=P)